# Access redis from angular application

Tags: angular, redis

I am new to angular and redish part, we have a application which access data from Dot.net api. Is it possible to use redish with angular application?

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use any database connection **directly** (also a in memory database, too) in a frontend app. This will show all sensible security data like login data.
Handle this with a server and send requests to it with the `httpClient` module from Angular.

```
this.httpClient.get("URLtoServer/getRedisData").subscribe({ next: (data) => {}, err: (err) => {...}});
```

And the server use redis and give a response back.

Greetings, Florian

Comment: Totally agree with Florian. However, if you want to be reckless and flaunt our advice, there is a tool called [Webdis](https://webd.is/) that creates a thin HTTP layer over Redis. Use with extraordinary caution.